# Return the result of a function input in procedure this result

Tags: sql, oracle

When the returned result of the function is one cd, the procedure is running. But when there are more than 2 cd the procedure does not accept the result and does not return a value. The goal is when the function returns multiple results that all those results call select that many times in the procedure.

```sql
create PACKAGE BODY  TEST_PACKAGE
  PROCEDURE GET_RESULTS(
    Date IN DATE,
    Cd IN NUMBER
  ) IS
    p_id NUMBER; 
    p_type;
    p_id1;
  BEGIN
    SELECT id, type, id1
    INTO p_id , p_type, p_id1
    FROM INFO_FUNCTION(Cd)
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN no_data_found THEN
       NULL;
  END;

  OPEN lcur FOR
    SELECT NAME,
           LAST NAME, 
           C.RESULT1
           C.RESULT2
           GET_DATE_FUNCTION(Date,Cd ) C
    FROM   TABLE1
  close lcur;
  GET_RESULTS;
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: your code without all the syntax errors (you say it works but it quite clearly will not as it is full of errors including a package body without a specification, calls to functions we do not have the code for, variables without types, missing `IS`/`END` for the package and missing commas). If you provide code that works (and all the dependencies and details of the error) then we might be able to debug it for you but if you provide something that won't even compile and an unrelated error message then it is difficult to help.

Comment: Тhe working code is very long, but I will make a shortened version that has no errors, thanks.

Comment: Is  INFO_FUNCTION a pipelined function? If yes, then you should have FROM table(INFO_FUNCTION(Cd)). Also, in the event it may return several rows, you should fetch in a loop. A for loop. Or, eventually, open a cursor and fetch only one row, then close the cursor. I really did not understand what that procedure is intended to do.

Comment: Yes is 
Is INFO_FUNCTION a pipelined function. The purpose of the procedure is to read the result
from the function
but the parameter of the function can sometimes be multiple and this requires the procedure to be called multiple times
depending on the number of parameters returned

Comment: @BogdanDincescu You do not need `TABLE(...)` on later Oracle versions. It is only the earlier versions that require that syntax. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vtrrip1y)

Comment: Obviously if your `select into` returns more than one row you'll get a `too_many_rows` exception. If that's the issue then you will need to change it to use a loop or something. Not really anything to do with pipelined functions.

Comment: I'll probably have to do a loop for that yes that's the problem I think too_many_rows

Answer (score 0):

You appear to just want to `CROSS JOIN` the pipelined table (and don't need the call to a separate function):

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PACKAGE
IS
  PROCEDURE GET_RESULTS(
    i_date IN  DATE,
    i_Cd   IN  NUMBER,
    o_cur  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  ) IS
  BEGIN
    OPEN o_cur FOR
      SELECT t1.name,
             t1.last_name, 
             c.result1,
             c.result2
      FROM   table1 t1
             CROSS JOIN TABLE(GET_DATE_FUNCTION(i_Date, i_Cd)) C;
  END get_results;
END;
/
```

or, if you are taking `Date` and `CD` values from `TABLE1` then use `CROSS APPLY` (or `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`):

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PACKAGE
IS
  PROCEDURE GET_RESULTS(
    o_cur  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  ) IS
  BEGIN
    OPEN o_cur FOR
      SELECT t1.name,
             t1.last_name, 
             c.result1,
             c.result2
      FROM   table1 t1
             CROSS APPLY TABLE(GET_DATE_FUNCTION(t1."DATE", t1.Cd)) c;
  END get_results;
END;
/
```